# how to display the total of each product type to another table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, display

[image]

[image]

HI, I Have here 2 different tables, what I want to do is display the total of each type of product from the 1st table to the 2nd table according to their corresponding types.

For example, I want to add all the products with type "JUMBO" from the 1st picture and display the total to the next table which have the same product type and do it for the product type.

btw, Im using windows for app c# in visual 2019 and sql server

```
class clsDtb
{
    const string DB_HOST = "localhost";
    const string DB_USER = "root";
    const string DB_PWD = "";
    const string DB_NAME = "rms_jl&e";
    const string CONN = @"SERVER=" + DB_HOST + ";" +
                            "UID=" + DB_USER + ";" +
                            "PWD=" + DB_PWD + ";" +
                            "DATABASE =" + DB_NAME + ";";

    //Retrieve Data
    public static DataTable QueryData(string _sql)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection _cn = new MySqlConnection(CONN))
        {
            try
            {
                _cn.Open();

                MySqlCommand _cmd = new MySqlCommand();

                _cmd.Connection = _cn;
                _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                _cmd.CommandText = _sql;

                using (MySqlDataReader _dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(_dr);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Connection " + err.Message, "Error Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

// its my class I use to retrive the table data from sql

and this the code to display it to may datagrid in my product form

```
string  SQL = @"SELECT  p.p_Date,prolist.prod_type ,p.p_Weight , p.p_Canister, u.FirstName
                    FROM productinventory p
                    INNER JOIN productslist prolist ON  p.prod_Code = prolist.prod_Code
                    INNER JOIN users u on p.userid = u.userid
                    ORDER BY p.p_Date DESC";
   
    private void frmProducts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userSQl = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '" + lblproid.Text.ToString() +"'";
        
        try
        {
            DataTable dtProducts = clsDtb.QueryData(SQL);
            DataTable user = clsDtb.QueryData(userSQl);
            if (dtProducts.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dgProducts.DataSource = dtProducts;
                
            }
            
            if (user.Rows[0]["Position"].ToString() != "Admin")
            {
                dgProducts.Columns["Delete"].Visible = false;
                dgProducts.Columns["Edit"].Visible = false;
                dgProducts.Columns["remittedby"].Visible = false;
                dgProducts.Columns["date"].Width = 200;
                dgProducts.Columns["type"].Width = 250;
                dgProducts.Columns["weight"].Width = 200;
                dgProducts.Columns["canister"].Width = 200;

            }
            else 
            {
                dgProducts.Columns["Delete"].Visible = true;
                dgProducts.Columns["Edit"].Visible = true;
                dgProducts.Columns["remittedby"].Visible = true;

            }
         }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Err" + err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        

    }
```

hope you guys understood what I mean, im actually new here thank you

Comment: When you use `C#`, please also include the code that you wrote so far. a TEXT, not as images... (see: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question))

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should learn about `Group By` a bootstrap on learning what you want is in [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby1).

Using `Group by` you can group your columns by something (in your example you want to show total number of your product).

I will add some pseudo codes as you didn't attached your model.

```
SELECT Product.Code, 
       Product.Title, 
       Count(*) AS TotalNumberOfProduct
INNER JOIN Store ON Store.ProductId = Product.Id
GROUP BY Product.Code, Product.Title
```

It will groups your records based on two column `Code` and `Title` and counts number of records with similar values.